# jQuery $("*").fadeTo() moves content before fading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does all content get jerked downwards before fading in the following, and how can i fix it?
*Using FireFox 3.6.3, thanks in advance.*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://localhost/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){   
                $("#button").click(function(){
                    $("*").fadeTo("slow",0.0);
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Just a normal paragraph doing my job!</p>
        <p>Me too!</p>
        <input type="button" id="button">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has something to do with trying to fade all elements, including those outside the `<body>`.  Try:

```
$("body > *").fadeTo(..)
```

But why would you want to fade every single element, when you can simply do a fade on the body itself.

```
$("body").fadeTo(..)
```

**Edit**: Some more research shows that when trying to fade the `<style>` and `<head>` elements, in no particular order, causes everything to move down. Don't know why yet, but you can see an example here - http://jsfiddle.net/UKn8r/2/

**Edit 2**: Ok, I think I may have a reason here. The `<head>` and its children elements such as `<style>`, `<script>`, etc. are by default set to `display: none` in the user agent's stylesheet. When fading them out, jQuery ends up setting their display property to `display: block`. Now the contents of these child elements are not meant to be displayed on the screen, but by setting them to `display: block`, it gets displayed as a horizontal block about 20px high with no content, which shifts everything else downwards. Note that if you were to empty out the `<script>` element and make the `onclick` inline, then you wouldn't see the jump on Firefox since the element will be empty and not consume any space on screen even when displayed as a block. So changing it to:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://localhost/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Just a normal paragraph doing my job!</p>
        <p>Me too!</p>
        <input type="button" id="button" onclick='$("*").fadeTo("slow",0.0);'>
    </body>
</html>
```

will not cause any jumps.

Also, your original code verbatim, will work properly on Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) as the `display` style property for `<script>` elements does not get overridden as `block`. For these browsers, however, if you were to have a `style` element with *some* content inside it, then you would see the same behavior as `<style>` will have an inline style attribute having `display: block`. Now it may seem utterly useless to have something like, `<style style="display: block; opacity: 0">..</style>`, but this is just an explanation for why you're seeing the behavior that you're seeing. So to reproduce the same problem on these browsers, try this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://localhost/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <style>p {}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Just a normal paragraph doing my job!</p>
        <p>Me too!</p>
        <input type="button" id="button" onclick='$("*").fadeTo("slow",0.0);'>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `<style>` property must have some content, and not pure whitespace, so I put the junk `p {}` there.

This concludes my wasteful search for something that shouldn't be done in the first place :)

Comment: +1 for `$("body").fadeTo`. Odd, I tried it and it didn't work for me. Probably did something wrong `:P`

Comment: @Kobi - I tried a quick test on fiddle, and it worked on Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/UKn8r/1/, didn't try other browsers, but it should work is my guess.

Answer (score 3):

Try to fade out your main container, or all elements at body level. For example:

```
$('body > *').fadeTo('slow', 0.3)
```

Fading out `*` doesn't look like a good idea. When you have nested elements (and you probably do), they will both be fade out, having odd effects and exceptionally poor performances.

Comment: Well, when jQuery is animating it changes `display` of elements. Not sure if `fadeTo` does that too.